# My one year old female jack russel keeps following and jumping all overnew staff pup

Tags: dogs, behavior

1 year old female Jack Russel terrier keeps jumping all over my new staff pup.At the beginning I thought that it was some mother instinct , but she just wont leave him alone  and now I think that she just wants to play. Am I right and how do I stop it? Thanks

Comment: At one year, she's still mostly puppy herself...

Answer (score 1):

So your dog has bad doggie manners. I don't think a puppy is going to be able to teach a teenager manners. : (

It's best to have a your Russel terrier hang out with trusted older dogs who do have good manners, to slowly teach him how to interact, and how to dog politely. Taking a bad-mannered dog to the dog park full of foreign dogs is a recipe for blood, so don't do that.

You can also intervene by constantly being relaxed, setting the tone of the play style you want. When she gets too rough, call her back to you (its cute to watch their apologetic smile), give her a pat for coming when called, and let her go back to playing.

Don't forget that both puppies need to learn proper socialization, and that's going to require meeting and hanging out with other dogs.

You can also look into doggie daycare, doggie bootcamp, or optionally dog training courses. Often there are puppy training / socialization courses, as well. If you are poor, look into your local kennel club rather than the big-box pet stores like Petsmart.